# JSON using loopj android listview failed

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous, get

I'm doing a Movie Project, I want to use parsing JSON to listview, I'm using loopj library, I already implement the code, but it does not work, the listview is still empty, I don't know where the error this is my code, I will show the item class first,

```
public class MovieItem  {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String rate;
    public  MovieItem(JSONObject object){
        try {
            String title = object.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("title");
            String description = object.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("overview");
            double movieRatet = object.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("vote_average");
            String movieRate = new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(movieRatet);
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.rate = movieRate;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

}
```

next, the loader is

```
 public ArrayList<MovieItem> loadInBackground() {
    Log.d("LOAD BG","1");
    SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
    final ArrayList<MovieItem> movieItemses = new ArrayList<>();
    final String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key="+API_KEY+"&language=en-US&query=annabelle";
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            setUseSynchronousMode(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String result = new String(responseBody);
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray list = responseObject.getJSONArray("list");

                for (int i = 0 ; i < list.length() ; i++){
                    JSONObject movie = list.getJSONObject(i);
                    MovieItem movieItems = new MovieItem(movie);
                    movieItemses.add(movieItems);
                }
                Log.d("REQUEST SUCCESS","1");
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("REQUEST FAILED","1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                              byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0 ; i< movieItemses.size() ; i++){
        Log.d("Title",movieItemses.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    Log.d("BEFORE RETURN","1");
    return movieItemses;
}

protected void onReleaseResources(ArrayList<MovieItem> data) {
    //nothing to do.
}
```

pls someone help me, I already fix this problem, but nothing different

FYI I'm using API from themoviedb

Comment: talk to me movieItemses.size == ???

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu what do you mean sir?

Comment: I want to know the size of movieItemses ?

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu size of what sir?,,sorry i didnt understand

Comment: This line: **Log.d("BEFORE RETURN","1");**
    return **movieItemses;**

Comment: ArrayList<MovieItem> movieList = loadInBackground();

Comment: Log.d("MovieList Size %s", movieList.size+"");

Comment: What is the value it returns?

Comment: the return of the value is 
movieItemses,,

movieItemses is ,,
final ArrayList<MovieItem> movieItemses= new ArrayList<>();

@NguyễnTrungHiếu

Comment: MovieItem is the class

Comment: No no.I want to know the size of movieItemses when use Log.d("MovieList Size %s", movieList.size+"");

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbol size,did u have telegram or any socmed sir?  :(
i didnt understand
@NguyễnTrungHiếu